# How to create a distance contour based on a road network that takes into account road preference?

Tags: gis, qgis, network-analysis

I am trying to create a series of contours describing the distance out from a single point along a road network that takes into account road user preference. So, motorway preference over all else, then A Road, then B etc. I have these listed in the road networks attribute table as a rough speed limit.

The crux of the issue is that I can't find a way to calculate these contours that actually takes these preferences into account. Is what I'm asking possible and how would I go about this?

I have tried using the plugin QNEAT3 - and the Iso-Areas to Contour function. This works fine for distance by road network but doesn't allow for adding weightings/preference to roads. Hence my problem!